# How to open sendmail receiving port

Tags: centos, sendmail, firewalld

I am trying to open port 25 for receiving mails from outside my server using sendmail. I want to read my mails with alpine and I don't need anything else.
I have tried this:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=25/tcp
```

connection is accepted by this command

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
```

but it is refused by this

```
telnet mydomain.com 25
```

How can I open this port for outside connections?

Comment: sendmail is installed.

Comment: You already opened the port in the firewall.

Comment: But it gives me connection refused. I cant find the problem.

Comment: How did you configure sendmail, then?

Comment: I solved the problem. sendmail was refusing connection. not firewall. I found a tutorial and configured sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: updated link (proofpoint have taken over sendmail)

[Sendmail FAQ 4.22 : Why can't I receive external mail?](https://www.proofpoint.com/us/sendmail/faq#gs-22)

> Several vendors have changed the way that sendmail is run. They decided that most people need a client-only version of sendmail. **So it is listening only on the localhost interface**. Check the system documentation on how to change your .mc file [...]

`netstat` command may be used to check if sendmail is listening only on the localhost interface (`127.0.0.1` or `::1`). It is `netstat -ant | grep :25` on Debian Linux.